# How to change the Wine or PlayOnLinux locale settings - Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wine, locale, playonlinux

According do [this](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-8945-MS_Excel_20072010_Change_number_format.html) post, Wine's locale settings (like numbering format) is based on Ubuntu locale settings.

If I have to change my Ubuntu locale settings, how can I change locale settings in Ubuntu 12.04, making sure that "monetary" and other numerical format settings will be updated too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change local in Ubuntu, go to ***System Settings*** --> ***language settings***, and click on the ***Regional Formats*** tab.  Change it to the desired country, and close the window.  Logoff, and log back in or reboot your system.

[image]