# How to change locale for Wine only?

Tags: 12.04, wine, locale

(Note this is a different question from [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167294/how-to-change-the-wine-or-playonlinux-locale-settings-ubuntu-12-04))

This is the output of the "locale" command on my machine:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I am happy with these settings and would like them to stay. But whenever I open a Wine application, I would like it to open with pl_PL.utf8 locale. In the terminal I can do this by typing

```
LC_ALL=pl_PL.utf8 wine myapp.exe
```

Is there a way to permanently change the default locale for Wine only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Winecfg does not have any option to change the language. The normal way is the method you posted.
- You will need to change the executable that you start and add the locale in front of it just like you do from command line.

Besides that ...

- it is old but [`winelocale`](https://code.google.com/p/winelocale/) might still work.

  > WineLocale clones the functionality of Microsoft AppLocale in Wine. It is used to manage locale and font settings in the Wine registry to ensure proper display of non-Latin type in pre-Unicode portable executables.

[image]

Comment: So... yes. `LC_ALL=pl_PL.utf8 wine myapp.exe` (or `LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8 ./myapp.exe` in my case).