# How do I change the locale of Wine to Japanese on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wine, japanese

I wish to run a game called "Morenatsu" on Ubuntu 14.04 via Wine. Morenatsu requires Applocale in Windows. Can I run Morenatsu in Applocale in Wine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change locale for Wine only?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286139/how-to-change-locale-for-wine-only)

Answer (score 5):

You can always run the game from the terminal instead of installing any other app and specify the language in the command:

```
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 wine /path/to/game/game.exe
```

In my case I wanted to play Saya no Uta (Japanese game with Japanese fonts) but it always showed squares and other non-Japanese symbols. I used to solve this kind of problem with AppLocale in Windows, but since I couldn't find an AppLocale replacement for Ubuntu then I launched the game through the terminal like this

Answer (score 2):

I remember that there was a tool called [WineLocale](https://code.google.com/p/winelocale/wiki/AddLocalesToDebian) that was made to mimic the functionality of AppLocale. But I have never really used it and the project site doesn't seem to offer any downloads.

A workaround seems to be to [create another profile with the locale the game should work with](https://askubuntu.com/a/167301/40581).